# how to solve Lorentz equation with $\sigma$ = o

Tags: dynamical-systems

Is it possible to solve the Lorentz equation below analytically with $\sigma$ =0 :
 $\dot x = \sigma(x-y)$;
$\dot y = \rho x-y -xz$;
$\dot z = xy - \alpha z$

If so, would it be appropriate to use the dissipative property?

Comment: With $\sigma=0$, $x$ is a constant, so the equations for $y$ and $z$ become linear with a constant source term, which is analytically solvable

Comment: Thanks. That was very helpful